# Javascript: add methods to function prototype

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

Is there a shorter way to write this:

```
var controller = function(){ 
    /*--- constructor ---*/
}; 

controller.prototype.function1 = function(){ 
    //Prototype method1
}

controller.prototype.function2 = function(){ 
    //Prototype method2
}

controller.prototype.function3 = function(){ 
    //Prototype method3
} 

return controller
```

I'm using require.js. I wondered if I can avoid the controller.prototype code repetition.

Comment: You could probably extend the prototype with an object, but why, there's nothing wrong with readability and typing "prototype" for each added prototype.

Comment: That's what I was wondering about :-) Continuous code repetition always seems suspicious to me.

Comment: you could do a ref shortcut pretty simply: var cp=controller.prototype; then cp.function3= ... you can also get fancy with object literals, or if you only need to support evirons that expose function.name, you can get really "classy"

Comment: That seems indeed like an obvious step forward. Thanks.

Comment: Though the answers given are all good, tossing out the use of jQuery's `extend` method as yet another option.  That is a very similar to the `protomix` function given below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### With a Helper Function

Even though this is longer than the answer given if you have to do this multiple places might be helpful to define a helper method:

```
function protomix(constructor, mix){
    for(var i in mix)
      if(mix.hasOwnProperty(i))
          constructor.prototype[i]=mix[i];
}

var controller = function(){
 //constructor
};

protomix(controller, {

   function1 :  function(){ 
       //Prototype method1
   },

   function2:  function(){ 
       //Prototype method2
   },

   function3 : function(){ 
    //Prototype method3
   } 
});

return controller;
```

### Using jQuery's extend method

I thought I should mention  [jQuery's extend method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)  because it was brought up in a comment and because in general has more functionality than the small helper method defined in the first part of the answer:

```
var controller = function(){ /* ctor */};
return $.extend(controller.prototype,{

   function1 :  function(){ 
       //Prototype method1
   },

   function2:  function(){ 
       //Prototype method2
   },

   function3 : function(){ 
    //Prototype method3
   } 
});
```

### Other Libraries

Other libraries also have similar functionality built in, such as [underscore's extend method](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) or [Lo-Dash's assign method](http://lodash.com/docs#assign)

Comment: I accept it, because you are right. I'm planning to use a lot of controllers in my application, so this function will come in very handy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you can also use the object destructuring.

```js
function Foo() {
}

Foo.prototype = {
  ...Foo.prototype,
  foo() {},
  bar() {},
  baz() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign(controller.prototype, { function1: ... })

Comment: You are better off using Object.defineProperties